# scale_shape_manual does not assign shapes, why?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot different shapes for A, B, C, but I cannot get `scale_shape_manual` to work.

```
Location = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
A = c(1.16, 0.96, 0.67,0.78, 0.55, 0.3,0.26)
B = c(6.51, 4.98, 2.85, 3.19, 3.60, 10.82, 8.60)
C = c(75.45, 86.66, 103.36, 123.2, 107.53, 128.9, 128.49)

library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

data = data.frame(Location, A,B,C)

data %>% pivot_longer(.,-Location, names_to = "var",values_to = "val") %>%
  filter(!is.na(val)) %>%
  mutate(NewVar = var) %>%
  add_row(., Location = c(1,1),
          var = c("B","B"),
          val = c(0,30),
          NewVar = c("Out","Out")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Location, y = val, group = NewVar, color = NewVar))+
  geom_point(size =2, colour = "black") +
  ylab("")+
  facet_wrap(.~var, strip.position = "left", ncol = 1, scales = "free_y", labeller = as_labeller(c(A= "A", B= "B", C= "C")))+
  theme_bw() + theme(text = element_text(size=15), axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black"), axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black"),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), strip.background = element_blank(),
    strip.placement = "outside")+
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:7) + theme(legend.position = "none") +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(1, 16, 21))
```

[image]

Comment: Scales only work for variables mapped in `aes()`, so you can set `aes(..., shape = my_variable)`  in the point layer (untested).

Comment: I agree with @teunbrand.  Also, you appear to overwrite your `color` ae in the following call to `geom_point`, so you won't get values of `NewVar` identified by colour - which has the value `"Out"` for every observation, so the reference within the call to `ae()` is unnecessary.

Comment: Ok, thanks @teunbrand I missed the Aesops, this now worked: ``geom_point(aes(Location, val, shape=var), size =2)``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what @teunbrand suggeststed and applied the colour corrections from @Limey

```
data %>% pivot_longer(.,-Location, names_to = "var",values_to = "val") %>%
  filter(!is.na(val)) %>%
  mutate(NewVar = var) %>%
  add_row(., Location = c(1,1),
          var = c("B","B"),
          val = c(0,30),
          NewVar = c("Out","Out")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Location, y = val, group = NewVar))+
  geom_point(aes(Location, val, shape=var), size =2) +
  ylab("")+
  facet_wrap(.~var, strip.position = "left", ncol = 1, scales = "free_y", labeller = as_labeller(c(A= "A", B= "B", C= "C")))+
  theme_bw() + theme(text = element_text(size=15), axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black"), axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black"),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), strip.background = element_blank(),
    strip.placement = "outside")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:7) + theme(legend.position = "none") +scale_shape_manual(values=c(19, 0, 15))
```

[image]